# Add string in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm building a menu items which the data are fetched from the database. I would like to add a class to all items even if the class from the array does not exist yet. However, when a class element does exist on the database, the initial class was getting overwritten.

What is the best practice to add class from the beginning? here's a sample code:-

```
$menu = [
  'title' => $title,
  'url' => $url,
  'attributes' => [
    'class' => 'link-item'
  ]
];

// assuming that the $data['attributes'] is the data fetched from the database
// assuming that the $data['attributes'] structure are as follows:-
// $data['attributes']['title'] = 'hello';
// the initial class set should be added to $data['attributes']['class']
// $data['attributes']['class'] should be 'link-item icon-something'
// $data['attributes']['class'] = 'icon-something';
// $data['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
if (isset($data['attributes'])) {
  $menu['attributes'] = $data['attributes'];
}
```

Please note that there's an admin ui to set more menu attributes.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the values rather than overwrite them, you will need something like this:

```
$menu = [
  'title' => 'old-title',
  'url' => 'http://example.com',
  'attributes' => [
    'class' => 'link-item'
  ]
];

$data['attributes']['title'] = 'hello';
$data['attributes']['class'] = 'icon-something';
$data['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';

if (isset($data['attributes'])) {
    foreach ($data['attributes'] as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($menu['attributes'][$key])) {
            $menu['attributes'][$key] .= ' ' . $value;
        }
        else {
            $menu['attributes'][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}

print_r($menu);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [title] => old-title
    [url] => http://example.com
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [class] => link-item icon-something
            [title] => hello
            [target] => _blank
        )    
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to just use `array_merge`:

```
$menu['attributes'] = array_merge($data['attributes'], $menu['attributes']);
```

This way any field that exists in `$data` and also in `$menu` would be overwritten by that from `$menu`.